# How to get JSON fields from Nested JSON Objects in Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm trying to get some JSON fields from this JSON response to put in a recyclerview using retrofit2. Below is my JSON response

[image]

**I don't know how to access the nested json objects fields. I ran this response through a JSon-Pojo converter and here are the data classes that were generated:**

-----------------------------------com.example.Article.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Article {

@SerializedName("source")
@Expose
private Source source;
@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
private Object author;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
@Expose
private String urlToImage;
@SerializedName("publishedAt")
@Expose
private String publishedAt;
@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
private String content;

public Source getSource() {
return source;
}

public void setSource(Source source) {
this.source = source;
}

public Object getAuthor() {
return author;
}

public void setAuthor(Object author) {
this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public String getUrlToImage() {
return urlToImage;
}

public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
}

public String getPublishedAt() {
return publishedAt;
}

public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
}

public String getContent() {
return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
this.content = content;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("totalResults")
@Expose
private Integer totalResults;
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
private List<Article> articles = null;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Integer getTotalResults() {
return totalResults;
}

public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
this.totalResults = totalResults;
}

public List<Article> getArticles() {
return articles;
}

public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
this.articles = articles;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Source.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Source {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Object id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public Object getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Object id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

**I just need to extract some fields from the article object but am lost on how to do this, any help is appreciated.**

Comment: What fields do you need to access? depending on that we can create one strategy or other

Comment: I need to access the source, author, title, description, publishedAt and  urlToImage fields from the Article  class

Comment: a bit confused about what you really need. It seems like you're pretty much there. Are you asking for general help with retrofit, as in, how to setup the calls and run them?

Comment: Yes when I setup the calls all I get returned is null values

Comment: The url is correct and everything.

Comment: show us how is your retrofit interface